# Making the getter/setter of an int?

Tags: objective-c

```
@property (retain) int myInteger;
```

That throws me an error because apparently `int` is not considered an object... but I want to get the advantage of creating a getter/setter method with the `@synthetize` thing, but with an `int`. How could I achieve so? Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
@property (assign) int chunkID;
```

or

```
@property (readonly) int chunkID;
```

You cannot retain a primitive type like integers. Only objects can be retained...

Comment: Is it alright if I use both? Do I have to put the @synthesize key twice or something?

Comment: No, for the same property, you only can choose if there are getter/setters methods ( first example ), or just a getter ( second example )

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int chunkID;
```

`assign` is the default so you might want to leave it out.

You need to use the `assign` type of property because you are dealing with a primitive object type (i.e. int). This kind of type can't be retained.

Only subclasses of NSObject can be retained / released.

Comment: It will be a good exercise for Omega to understand if it does.

Comment: @Omega: Please read  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html